# Car door lock with 5v relay

Tags: current, relay, automotive

i want to close and open car door lock. Somthing like this:
[image]

Its 12v and 10amp :

[image]

Fo running this device i just need to send puls for maximum 500ms . My question is this : for 500ms can i use this 5v relay (3A) and if not why ?whats about 24v door lock?

[image]

Comment: A relay will have a higher voltage spec for AC than for DC. That's what you see there. It can tolerate up to 24 volts DC and switch 3 amps. That does NOT mean it can switch 10 amps at 12 volts DC, which seems to be what you actually want. Options: (1) Select a relay that is rated for the current and voltage; (2) accept that this relay may fuse and lock up when you would very much rather it didn't; (3) use semiconductors, instead, but this requires circuit design, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"My question is this : for 500ms can i use this 5v relay (3A) and if not why ?"*

I would advise you to use switches made of semiconductors like MOSFET for switching which are more fast switching components than the magnetic relays. These magnetic relays are not much sensitive and efficient at high switching frequencies. While, on the other hand, switches like MOSFETs don't have a moving part inside those which makes them very reliable.

*"whats about 24v door lock?"*
My anwser would be same for this question as well. While chosing switching components, the frequency of switching is more important than the voltage. Of course you can easily find MOSFET of 12V and 24V ratings.

Comment: Why would we care about "high switching frequencies" for a door lock actuator? Why, in this application, is "the frequency of switching is more important than the voltage"? Won't the MOSFET be destroyed if the voltage applied to it is too high?

Answer (score 5):

The question is not whether you can, it is whether you should, and you should not.

And for a 10A load, a relay that is only rated to switch 3A is not a good idea, because the contacts are not rated for switching 10A. The contacts can heat up more than intended due to the current, so they can degrade faster and might even weld together. Especially when switching DC into inductive load.